# Why Ubuntu is highly recommended for uWSGI and Nginx installation?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am new to Django integration with uWSGI and Nginx. Most of the tutorials in internet requires Ubuntu to test it.

I am on Windows, Does they work in Windows ?

If not should I install Ubuntu / Linux OS to work with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why Ubuntu/Linux is recommended:

- NGINX itself has some [known issues](https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues) if running on Windows. It is generally recommended to run it on *NIX systems
- Ubuntu is the most popular Linux distribution

You can easily install/run NGINX without issues on virtually any Linux distro, but the number of tutorials for Ubuntu specifically will be prevalent due to its popularity.

That said, I personally choose CentOS/RHEL as it's more targeted towards enterprise/security, which sounds like something quite needed for web hosting.

Comment: Thans, I will look into CentOS/RHEL